# Tournament problems

Tags: python, recursion, time, execution

We had this little assignment to create tournaments of n teams, that have to play m games each on o courts with 3 rules:

1. A game must not be played more than once
2. A team cannot play against itself
3. The difference in times a team has played cannot be greater than one at any given time in the tournament.

The code below solves this, but apparently is very very slow. I know there is a solution about a million times faster (and is also in C++ but I don't believe that's making more than a thousand fold difference), but don't know that code.

Does anyone have suggestions about making below code faster. It's suppost to do backtracking for finding answers (allowed tournaments). Evaluate sees if the tournament is still allowed, extend keeps (recursively) adding games from the all_possible_games stack if the tournament still validates. E designates an empty field, which is only allowed in the last round. For 2-30 teams on various field counts etc the program works fine. But 100 teams on 50 courts with 10 games per team should be solvable in 0.001 sec. This program takes hours...

```
import math


def printtournament(tournament):
    for gameround in grouped(tournament, fields):
        for game in sorted(gameround, key=lambda x: x[0] if isinstance(x[0], int) else 0):
            if game[0] != 'E':
                print(game, end='')
        print()
    print()


def grouped(iterable, n):
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)


def allgames(teamcount):
    games = []
    for t in range(teamcount):
        for u in range(teamcount):
            if u is not t:
                game = (u, t)
                game = sorted(game, reverse=False)
                if game not in games:
                    games.append(game)
    return games


def evaluate(tournament, fieldcount, gamesperteam, teamcount):
    current_games_per_team = {}

    for i in range(teamcount):
        current_games_per_team[i] = 0
    current_games_per_team['E'] = 0
    gamehasbeenplayed = []
    current_games_per_team_round = {}
    for i in range(teamcount):
        current_games_per_team_round[i] = 0
    current_games_per_team_round['E'] = 0

    for gameround in grouped(tournament, fieldcount):
        teamhasplayed = []

        for game in (gameround):
            for t in game:
                if t in teamhasplayed and t is not 'E':
                    return False
                else:
                    teamhasplayed.append(t)
            if game in gamehasbeenplayed and game[0] is not 'E' and game[1] is not 'E':
                return False
            else:
                gamehasbeenplayed.append(game)

            current_games_per_team[int(game[0]) if isinstance(game[0], int) else 'E'] += 1
            current_games_per_team[int(game[1]) if isinstance(game[0], int) else 'E'] += 1
            current_games_per_team_round[int(game[0]) if isinstance(game[0], int) else 'E'] += 1
            current_games_per_team_round[int(game[1]) if isinstance(game[0], int) else 'E'] += 1

            for k, c in current_games_per_team.items():
                if c > gamesperteam and k is not 'E':
                    return False

        for k1, c in current_games_per_team_round.items():
            for k2, d in current_games_per_team_round.items():
                if abs(c - d) > 1 and k1 is not 'E' and k2 is not 'E':
                    return False
    return True

def extend(gamecount, games, teams, fields, gamesperteam):
    if gamecount < games:
        for game in all_possible_games:
            tournament[gamecount] = game
            for i in range(fieldrounds):
                if i > gamecount:
                    tournament[i] = ['E', 'E']
            if evaluate(tournament, fields, gamesperteam, teams):
                extend(gamecount+1, games, teams, fields, gamesperteam)
    else:
        printtournament(tournament)


teams = 30
fields = 4
gamesperteam = 2
games = int(teams/2*gamesperteam)
fieldrounds = int(math.ceil(games/fields)*fields)
all_possible_games = allgames(teams)
tournament = []
for i in range(fieldrounds):
    tournament.append(['E', 'E'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    extend(0, games, teams, fields, gamesperteam)
```

Comment: Your code has time complexity so high that I can't do the math at some points... For example your functions `printtournament` has O(N)^2 and `allgames()` has O(N)^2, and then evaluate has O(N)^3 in the middle, so for each tournament added, your code roughly has a*a time and for each game added you have a*a time, and for each evaluate you have a*a*a time. So if you have 100 teams and 10 games per team you have (1000 games) * (1000 games) * (1000 games) time complexity which is already a billion. You need to find better ways to deal with some of those nested for loops.

Comment: printtournament and allgames are only executed once, in less than a 0.001 second

Comment: I assume so, check `if evaluate(tournament, fields, gamesperteam, teams): extend(gamecount+1, games, teams, fields, gamesperteam)` as the bottleneck.

Comment: That's the heart of the backtracking by recursion...

Comment: I see evaluate is complex by how to simplify?